# Как использовать член шаблонного базового класса в зависимом наследнике?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, наследование

```
struct A {
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename q>
struct Base {
    explicit Base(A a) : a(a) {}

    A a;
};

template<typename q>
struct Derived : Base<q> {
    Derived() : Base<q>(A()) {
        a.foo(); // почему не работает?
    }
};

int main() {
    new Derived<int>();
}
```

> error: 'a' was not declared in this scope

Comment: в структурах  Base и Derived   неиспользуемый аргумент шаблона, и  вы могли наверное найти в альфовите другую букву, чтоб не писать  a(a)...

Comment: Ну еслибы структуры не были шаблонными, то все работало бы,

Answer (score 3):

Если базовый класс является *зависимым* шаблонным типом, то поиск *неквалифицированных* имен в таком базовом классе не производится. К именам из такого базового класса следует обращаться либо по квалифицированному имени (`Base<q>::a.foo()`), либо через явный `this` (`this->a.foo()`).

Comment: наверное  Base<q>(A()) создается  только в точке инстанцирования, потому и нужна явная квалификация: так ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: Я, честно говоря, не знаю, почему так сделано. Связей с точками инстанциирования навскидку не вижу. В стандарте просто сказано в лоб, что такие базовые классы не просматриваются при поиске и все.

Comment: ну  просто логически так должно было и быть, но лично я внятно не могу обьяснить, просто понимаю, что раз с каждым параметром будем иметь разные типы, и разные обьекты будем иметь соответственно, поэтому   часто получится хаос, если язык не требовал бы явной квалификации

Comment: По-моему такое усложнение необходимо, чтобы еще на этапе разбора шаблона (т.е. до инстанцирования) показать компилятору, к чему относится неизвестный идентификатор `a`.