# Псевдонимы типов в шаблонных классах

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Пример:

```
#include <utility>       // std::pair
#include "vertex.hpp"    // IVertex class 

template <typename Key>
class IEdge {
public:
    using   VertexPtr = IVertex<Key>*;
    using Endvertices = std::pair<VertexPtr, VertexPtr>;
// ...
public:
    Endvertices& endvertices() noexcept = 0;    
};

template <typename Key = int>
class Edge : public IEdge<Key> {
public:
    // interface: IEdge
    Endvertices& endvertices() noexcept override;
};
```

Компилятор выдает огромное количество ошибок связанных с отсутствием кейворда `typename` и добавление последнего не помогает.

Вопрос: как с этим бороться? Должен ли я перед каждым псевдонимом указывать базовый класс с текущим шаблонным параметром, вроде:

```
typename IEdge<Key>::Envertices
```

Если так, то прошу объяснить, чем обусловливается такая необходимость в контексте использования шаблонов.

Comment: Для удобства добавьте в дочерний класс `using Envertices_t = typename IEdge<Key>::Envertices;`, чтобы не повторять эту писанину везде.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо, полезный совет!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, в дочернем классе при обращении к типам базового класса следует обязательно указывать префикс с именем класса и `typename`. Дело в том, что до инстанцирования шаблона наличие в базовом шаблонном классе `IEdge` тех или иных компонентов еще не известно (так как они могут варьироваться в зависимости от праметра `Key`) и компилятор не способен определить происхождение идентификатора `Endvertices`.

Comment: простите за наглость, можете указать место в стандарте, где об этом прочесть можно? Думаю, другим бы это позже так же бы пригодилось :)

Comment: > могут варьироваться в зависимости от праметра Key - это как если бы мы написали _что-то_ с ```std::enable_if```? Типа, из-за таких кейсов мы обязаны это делать?

Comment: @isnullxbh В стандарте этому посвящен раздел `17.7.2 Dependent names [temp.dep]`

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @isnullxbh Пример: можно написать специализацию `IEdge<int>` совсем без `Endvertices`

Comment: Понял, спасибо за разъяснение!

Answer (score 3):

У вас тут перемешались две независимые проблемы.

Во-первых, никакого отношения к отсутствию `typename` ошибки в этом коде не имеют. Ошибки в этом коде вызваны тем, что в ситуациях, когда базовый класс является зависимым типом, обыкновенный поиск *неквалифицированных* имен не будет выполнять поиск в этом базовом классе. Поэтому использованные в классе-наследнике неквалифицированные имена вроде `Endvertices` найдены не будут. (см., например, [Ошибка в иерархии классов 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799493/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-2))

`typename` здесь ни при чем. Неудивительно, что добавление `typename` не помогает.

Во-вторых, если бы речь шла о полях или методах базового класса, проблему можно было бы решить либо обращением через `this->...`, либо обращением через *квалифицированное* имя `IEdge<Key>::...`. Для имен типов же применим только второй вариант. И так как тип `IEdge<Key>` является зависимым, то вот тут-то и вступит в силу правило, требующее указания `typename` в ссылках на вложенные типы. (см., например, [C++ ошибка dependent name is not a type, prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843983/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-dependent-name-is-not-a-type-prefix-with-typename-to-indicate-a-ty?noredirect=1))

Comment: Спасибо за оъяснение!